# ¿Como puedo consultar varios modelos con django cuando el usuario lo consulte en una barra de busqueda?

Tags: python, django, backend

Estoy realizando un sistema de inventario que permita al usuario listar, registrar, editar, eliminar articulos del inventario. Lo que deseo es que el usuario consulte por una barra de busqueda ingresando el codigo o nombre del articulo y le aparezca todos los datos referentes al articulo indicando en que departamento se encuentra. Estos son mis modelos

```
class Departamento(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nombre', unique=True)

class InventarioBase(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key= True)
codigoDelBien = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='N° Provisional del Bien', unique=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nombre')
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Descripcion')
caracteristica = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Caracteristicas')
estado = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Estado de Conservacion')
departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name='Departamento')
observacion = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Observacion', null=True, blank=True)
```

Los demas departamentos como poseen los mismos atributos heredan de InventarioBase como por ejemplo:

```
class InventarioAdministracion(InventarioBase):
      codigo...
```

Los demas departamentos son iguales....

```
class OtrosDepartamentos(InventarioBase):
      codigo...
```

en mis views.py

```
def busqueda(request):
busqueda = request.GET.get('buscar')
administracion = InventarioAdministracion.objects.all()

if busqueda:
    administracion = InventarioAdministracion.objects.filter(
        Q(codigoDelBien = busqueda) |
        Q(nombre = busqueda) |
        Q(descripcion = busqueda) |
        Q(caracteristica = busqueda) |
        Q(estado = busqueda) |
        Q(departamento = busqueda) |
        Q(observacion = busqueda)
    ).distinct()
    
context= {
    'administracion': administracion
}

return render(request, 'busquedaInventario.html', context)
```

mi barra de busqueda

```
<div class="content">
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h2 class="text-center display-4">Busqueda</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                <form method="GET">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Ingrese Codigo del Bien Mueble a Buscar" name="buscar">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

En mi template

```
         <thead>
            
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">N° PROVISIONAL DEL BIEN</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">NOMBRE</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">DESCRIPCION</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">CARACTERISTICAS</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">ESTADO</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">UBICACION</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">OBSERVACION</th>
          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
          {% for i in administracion %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ i.codigoDelBien }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.nombre }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.descripcion }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.caracteristica }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.estado }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.departamento}}</td>
            <td>{{ i.observacion }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %} 

        </tbody>
```

Me funciona pero solo me aparecen los que se encuentran en administracion, lo que quiero es que haga una busqueda general del articulo con el codigo o nombre que se le consulte y aparezcan todos los datos incluyendo el departamento en el que se encuentra

E estado investigando y e tenido mas preguntas que respuestas

Cualquier ayuda estaria muy agradecido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi asi si a alguien le sirve, si quiero buscar un dato que se encuentra en un query, agrego el metodo exist() y si encuentra el valor que ingreso el usuario devuelve un booleano ya sea True o False, y si es verdadero lo envia al template y se pueden mostrar los datos, pero si es falso no devuelve nada.

Puede que exista una manera mejor o mas optima de hacerlo pero investigando llegue a este metodo y me funciono.

```
def busqueda(request):

     busqueda = request.GET.get('buscar') # tomamos el valor del template

     if busqueda:
    
        resultado = ""
    
        if InventarioAdministracion.objects.filter(codigoDelBien__icontains=busqueda).exists() == True:

            resultado = InventarioAdministracion.objects.all()
    
             context= {
                'resultado': resultado
             }

            return render(request, 'busquedaInventario.html', context)

     else:
    
         return render(request, 'busquedaInventario.html')
```